# better understanding scope directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have rows and cols as followed:

```
      <ul class="ulgen clearfix" >
        <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat='game in games| limitTo:limitrows'> 
           <div class="col1">{{game.id}}</div>
           <div class="col2">
              <span winner1 id="g{{$parent.$index+game.id}}1" ng-click="check($parent.$index,game.id,1)" data-row="{{game.id}}" data-col="{{$parent.$index+1}}" data-type="1" data-checked="0" class="gamebtncommen">
                 {{game.value| split:'-':0}}
              </span>
           </div> 
           <div class="col3">
              <span winner1 id="g{{$parent.$index+game.id}}0" ng-click="check($parent.$index,game.id,0)" data-row="{{game.id}}" data-col="{{$parent.$index+1}}" data-type="0" data-checked="0" class="gamebtncommen">X</span>
           </div> 
           <div class="col4">
              <span winner1 id="g{{$parent.$index+game.id}}2" ng-click="check($parent.$index,game.id,2)" class="gamebtncommen" data-row="{{game.id}}" data-col="{{$parent.$index+1}}" data-type="2" data-checked="0">
                 {{game.value| split:'-':1}}
              </span>
           </div>
        </li>
```

then I have built this directive:

```
   tmControllers.directive('winner1', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     scope.check = function(col, row, type) {
        col++;
        console.log(element);
        var el = element//$('.gamebtncommen[data-row="' + row + '"][data-col="' + col + '"][data-type="' + type + '"]');
        if (el.hasClass('orangeback')) {
           el.removeClass('orangeback');
           element.attr('data-checked', 0);
           scope.clacprice();
        } else {
           el.addClass('orangeback').data('checked', 1);
           element.attr('data-checked', 1);
           scope.clacprice();
        }
     }

     scope.clacprice = function() {

        var siz = $('.gamebtncommen[data-col="1"][data-checked="1"]').size();

        console.log(siz);
```

the problem is that a row is getting same scope when checking the span, I want that the directive will change each span data, each row get data checked 1, while I would expact it to be 3 if 3 spans are checked

Comment: Check this blog: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

You should define the **scope** property of **directive**. If you are not aware of **directive scope** then for reference we can define **scope** of a **directive** in three ways, which are

- **isolated scope**
- **inherited scope**,
- **same/parent scope**.

By default all **directives** have **same/parent scope** (the third option). You can check out more about **directive scope** on the [scope-in-angularjs](http://codechutney.in/blog/angularjs/scope-in-angularjs/) blog.

Comment: nice post, so in my case scope: true, will solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Creating Isolate Scope in a Directive
Isolating the scope in a directive is a is a simple process. Start by adding a scope property into the directive as shown next. This automatically isolates the directive’s scope from any parent scope(s).

```
tmControllers.directive('winner1', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},

    };
});
```

Comment: it is working properly in the controller, is it right to do it without directive at all?